# Stuck with connecting to mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb

I was about to start using mongodb as my database project. I'm always stuck when want to pushing some data to it. I use mongodb atlas. This code below always resulting errors. I've following and learning about mongodb from online (like youtube, w3, etc)

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient

url = "mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0.oecqh.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
cluster = MongoClient(url)
db = cluster["discord"]
collection = db["discord"]

push = {"name": "test", "value": "test"}
try:
    collection.insert_one(push)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

The errors

```
Exception ignored in: <function Client.__del__ at 0x00000213C5D84940>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\httpx\_client.py", line 1139, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\httpx\_client.py", line 1111, in close
    self._transport.close()
AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute '_transport'
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\dns\win32util.py", line 48, in run
    self.info.domain = _config_domain(interface.DNSDomain)
  File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\dns\win32util.py", line 26, in _config_domain
    if domain.startswith('.'):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymongo\srv_resolver.py", line 89, in _resolve_uri
    results = _resolve(
  File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymongo\srv_resolver.py", line 43, in _resolve
    return resolver.resolve(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\dns\resolver.py", line 1193, in resolve
    return get_default_resolver().resolve(qname, rdtype, rdclass, tcp, source,
  File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\dns\resolver.py", line 1063, in resolve
    (nameserver, port, tcp, backoff) = resolution.next_nameserver()
  File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\dns\resolver.py", line 646, in next_nameserver
    raise NoNameservers(request=self.request, errors=self.errors)
dns.resolver.NoNameservers: All nameservers failed to answer the query _mongodb._tcp.cluster0.oecqh.mongodb.net. IN SRV:

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Documents\Programming\Python\tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 5, in <module>
    cluster = MongoClient(url)
  File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 704, in __init__
    res = uri_parser.parse_uri(
  File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymongo\uri_parser.py", line 542, in parse_uri
    nodes = dns_resolver.get_hosts()
  File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymongo\srv_resolver.py", line 121, in get_hosts
    _, nodes = self._get_srv_response_and_hosts(True)
  File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymongo\srv_resolver.py", line 101, in _get_srv_response_and_hosts
    results = self._resolve_uri(encapsulate_errors)
  File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymongo\srv_resolver.py", line 97, in _resolve_uri
    raise ConfigurationError(str(exc))
pymongo.errors.ConfigurationError: All nameservers failed to answer the query _mongodb._tcp.cluster0.oecqh.mongodb.net. IN SRV:
```

Comment: Doesn't seem like it is an issue with pushing a document, but connecting in general. Seems like it cannot resolve the URI. When you use that "mongodb+srv" connection string in your Mongo client like Compass or Studio3T does it work fine?

Comment: @DFW, when using URL for connecting to Mongo Compass it says 'bad auth .....' and I need to put my username and password manually (I mean there is advanced option right in the bottom one?). But when I want to use it as string to connect it from python it shows like I showed it before

Comment: I hope this isn't too obvious but in python and in mongo compass, you've actually replaced <username> and <password> with the actual values, right? You're just hiding it here for obvious security concerns (which is good). If so, then I'd try connecting with the non-mongodb+srv connection format. I'll look it up tomorrow

Comment: I used to use a non mongodb+srv connection style like: 
`pymongo.MongoClient('<server>:<port>', username='<username>', password='<password>', authSource='<db_auth_source>', tls=True, tlsCAFile='<CA_file_location>', replicaset='<replica_set_name>')`. You may not need all those parameters like tls, tlsCAFile, or replicaset, but I wanted to include them just in case.